# Database still slow after index added

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with 2 million rows. when using `order by firstname` which `firstname` is not an index, the database is extremely slow.

I added an index for `firstname` and I thought it will speed up! no luck.

is there anything else I am missing?

explain extended:

1   SIMPLE  doctors ALL                 1244888 100.00  Using filesort

Comment: Please include your [explain extended](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html) plan.

Comment: @Payam added. is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does something called late lookup and the way to solve it is to wrap the order by inside a subquery. You can read the details at http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/